# call shourtcut in c# in wpf

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts

how can I assign a keyboard shortcut to open new window or make any function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [`CommandBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.aspx) :

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding 
        Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"
        Executed="_HandleApplicationOpenCommandExecute"/>        
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```